# Generic storage of primitive data types

Tags: c, pointers

Storage is some chunk of memory:

```
U08* storage;
```

Current implementation only accepts read/write of U32 data.

```
U32 read(void* storage_somewhere) {
    return *(U32*)storage_somewhere;
}

void write(void* storage_somewhere, U32 data_u32) {
    *(U32*)storage_somewhere = data_u32;
}
```

Is this standard practice in C?
Is it assumed that I should memcpy into an U32 when storing other data-types?

Given that I need:

- Read/write values of 1/2/4 bytes, signed/unsigned/floating
- Portable code (required to run on some embedded system)

My understanding is that implementing something like:

```
void read(void* storage_somewhere, void* data_ptr, DATA_TYPE data_type)
void write(void* storage_somewhere,void* data_ptr, DATA_TYPE data_type)
```

with specific pointer casts based on data_type:

```
switch(data_type)
...
   case tF32:
       *(F32*)storage_somewhere = val_f32
...
```

would lead to undefined behavior.

What is the recommended approach? I assume one should use memcpy instead - but that means i could just use keep the existing functionality.

Comment: Casts may sometimes violate strict aliasing. `memcpy` is the foolproof way of doing it. In any case, I'm not sure I completely understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: How do you get the value for `storage_somewhere`? If you supply an address that is not sufficiently aligned for your data type you might get an alignment trap when you use pointer casts, e.g. if you supply an odd address to access a 16bit or 32bit value. In this case you might have to use `memcpy`.

Comment: The more you can avoid `void*` and cast the better it is, let the compiler helps you producing warnings/errors when your code is wrong (supposing types known). Note _unions_ allow to manages several possible types of data, and to add an associated discriminant is a good way to do (so having typically a _struct_ memorizing the _union_ and the discriminant).

Comment: Ah, well, storage_somewhere is guaranteed to offer 4 bytes, although sometimes only one is used.

Comment: @bruno Forgot to mention that type-punning via union is not allowed

Comment: The question related to the internals of the ”storage framework”. The exposed functions will only accept specific types (u08/s16/f32 etc)

Comment: @aberg As long as you follow the rules for a union then there is no type punning.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this standard practice in C? Is it assumed that I should memcpy
>   into an U32 when storing other data-types?

It depends on what you mean by "this".  Converting object pointers back and forth between type `void *` and other object pointer types is relatively common, and it serves reasonable purposes (and sometimes unreasonable ones).  On the other hand, it is not typical at all to maintain a flat pool of memory into- and out of which you write and read values of varying type.

But if you want something that serves as a flat pool of primitives, then a union of arrays would probably be a better choice:

```
#define WORD_COUNT 1024

union {
    int8_t   as_schars[WORD_COUNT * 4];
    uint8_t  as_uchars[WORD_COUNT * 4];
    int16_t  as_sshorts[WORD_COUNT * 2];
    uint16_t as_ushorts[WORD_COUNT * 2];
    int32_t  as_sints[WORD_COUNT];
    uint32_t as_uints[WORD_COUNT];
    float    as_floats[WORD_COUNT];  // assumes 32-bit floats
} primitives;
```

You may then access elements directly, without function calls, via expressions such as

```
uint8_t a_byte = primitives.as_uchars[42];
int16_t a_short = primitives.as_sshorts[222];
float f = primitives.as_floats[665];

primitives.as_uints[1] = 12;
```

You then also have no risk of undefined behavior arising from casting pointers back and forth and dereferencing the results.

---

Alternatively, if your storage is divided into 32-bit units then you have a couple of other union-based alternatives based around a union for individual units such as this:

```
union primitive {
    int8_t   as_schar;
    uint8_t  as_uchar;
    int16_t  as_sshort;
    uint16_t as_ushort;
    int32_t  as_sint;
    uint32_t as_uint;
    float    as_float;  // assumes 32-bit floats
};
```

- Provided that you can ensure that such a union has no padding, you can use that as your base type for storage and data exchange:

  ```
  union primitive prim = /* ... */;

  uint8_t a_byte = prim.as_uchar;
  int16_t a_short = prim.as_sshort;
  float f = prim.as_float;
  ```
- If you cannot assume or ensure that such a union has the correct storage size, then it's probably still better to use it for storing and recovering data than to use `memcpy`:

  ```
  int16_t read_s16(uint32_t *storage_somewhere) {
      return ((union primitive) { .as_uint = *storage_somewhere }).as_sshort;
  }

  void write_float(uint32_t *storage_somewhere, float data) {
      *storage_somewhere = ((union primitive) { .as_float = data }).as_uint;
  }
  ```

Those alternatives make it as clear as possible to the compiler what you're doing, and it is more likely to generate optimal code for that than for the `memcpy` case.